# RAILS - Resource Pooling Options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have a set of sessions for a third-party application I'm using.

I was planning on building a table to store the 10 or so sessions details I need for this and then writing a pool around this. Dishing out one of the unused connections as needed and then dropping it back in the pool when finished.

I was wondering if there are any good wrappers or gems out there that can handle some of this logic for me? It's one of those things that sounds like it should be simple, but I'm sure it'll end up being more complex than I imagine!

Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

Adding a bit more color

The third party application I'm using (OpenTok) provides web conferencing sessions. Once you open a session you're passed a session key (essentially just a string key). This key allows you to connect and disconnect from the session indefinitely.

If you want to have multiple sessions they recommend storing these sessions and reusing them when you want to open the session up.

I'd like to create maybe 10 or so of these sessions, store the 10 session keys in a table and then wrap a pool around these. They could be cached into memory on startup or read from the table each time.

I was just curious if there was any gems out there that handled this sort of pooling concept for a resource. In Java I might have used something like Apache Commons for the pooling for instance.

Comment: So, what is the question? Are you asking how to pool database connections or what?

Comment: No it's not database connections, I leave that to the Rails connection pool. As I mentioned these are session objects for a third party application I'm using.

Comment: So, it's about 'locking' database rows then? I doubt that there are gems for that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else decides to look into this. There are actually quite a few options out there that do just this.

Some examples are:

https://github.com/guyboertje/client_pool
https://github.com/jugend/common-pool

Comment: Also:
https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool
https://github.com/bpardee/gene_pool